# Cannot find .bowerrc file

Tags: php, ubuntu, proxy, bower

I am trying to install Learning Locker on my Ubuntu 14.04 which runs apache2 and php5, I have installed all the dependencies listed [here](http://docs.learninglocker.net/installation/). How ever when I run composer (actually its composer.phar, I dont know why) it shows that its downloading but bower shows ECONNRESET errors all along. So i figured I had to set the proxy but cannot find .bowerrc file, I searched in home and root directories. Am I doing something wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manually create this file.

```
cd /your/working/dir
touch .bowerrc
```

`.bowerrc` contents:

```
{ 
   "proxy": "http://<host>:<port>",
    "https-proxy": "http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

Other locations:

> The config is obtained by merging multiple configurations by this
>   order of importance:
>
> 1. CLI arguments via --config
> 2. Environment variables
> 3. Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
> 4. All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
> 5. .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (~)
> 6. .bowerrc file located in the global folder (/)

More: [docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/#proxy)

Comment: I cant understand. There are no `.bowerrc` in current directory or home or in root directory, also can you please be more specific on how to merge the CLI configurations to generate the file? I cant understand the doc part, what does `--config.endpoint-parser=<parser>` mean? How do I generate the `.bowerrc` using that

Comment: You don't need `--config.endpoint-parser=<parser>` in this case. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Although I have run into different problems though, not concerning this. I'll refer their github page instead. Thanks again!